# how to change the name of tinymce menubar items

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to rename items in a menubar in tinyMce Editor so I can translate them. I managed to change her title, but not the sub-items like undo or redo.

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
 menu: {
   file: {title: 'Arquivo', items: 'newdocument'},
   edit: {title: 'Editar', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
   insert: {title: 'Inserir', items: 'link media | template hr'},
   view: {title: 'Visualizar', items: 'visualaid'},
   format: {title: 'Formatar', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
   table: {title: 'Tabela', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
   tools: {title: 'Ferramentas', items: 'spellchecker code'}
 }
});
```

If anyone knows what to do it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyMCE is already localized into a large number of languages including Spanish so you don't need to do this manually.

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#usingthecommunitylanguagepacks

Assuming you have the correct language pack downloaded and deployed into the correct place you simply need to tell TinyMCE to use that language pack:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  language: 'es'
});
```

Comment: Thank you, friend!